# Nodejs express - send the response of the POST request from client back to client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am working on HTML form handling data to server (using express and nodejs) and back to client. Below are my procedures.

```
//My folder structure
-index.js
-public
 -index.html
 -timer.html
-...
```

1. HTML form (index.html) send POST request to server

```
<form method="POST" action="/timer">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

2. Server can receive the POST request, I can console.log(req.body). (Works)
3. Then I want to pass back the data to client, by sending a html file (timer.html under public folder) and the data. (Not works)

```
app.post('/timer', urlencodedParser, (req,res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  res.sendFile('public/timer.html' , { root : __dirname, data: req.body});
})
```

4. If works, how can the variable (data) display in the timer.html (file send back to client)?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: what do you want to do with the data back on the client ? if you just want to display them, you have to render/embed them in the html file, keyword: template engine. But what you are trying does not work and makes no sense

Comment: Yes. I want to display the data in the html file I send back to client. But my method doesn't work. The problem should be below code.           
res.sendFile('public/timer.html' , { root : __dirname, data: req.body});

Comment: No. thats not the problem. https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.sendFile hast not `data` property. you have to use a template engine like handlebars/mustache or what ever else!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, for the template engine, is that like ejs?